# How to apply function to each group of panel data (with data.table?) in R?

Tags: r, function, matrix, data.table

I have a basic knowledge of R and I try to automate some calculations on a data frame. I created a function and some code and would like some help to align everything with the R philosophy.

I have a panel dataset df that you can build as such:

```
# sample data frame
id <- c("i","i","i","j","j","j","k","k")
time <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2)
b1 <- c(1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0)
b2 <- c(0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1)
b3 <- c(0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0)
b4 <- c(0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1)
df <- data.frame(id,time,b1,b2,b3,b4)
```

I tranform it using data.table as such:

```
# data.table
### set-up
dt <- data.table(df)
setkey(dt,id,time)

### lead
nm1 <- grep("^b", colnames(dt), value=TRUE)
nm2 <- paste("lead", nm1, sep=".")
dt[, (nm2) := shift(.SD, type='lead'), by = id, .SDcols=nm1]
```

Now, I want to compute for each group *id* a matrix adding all the transitions from one row to the next one. Each matrix is stored into a list. I created a function that I apply to each group as such:

```
# empty list
m.out <- list()

# group i
m <- matrix(0,cat,cat + 1)
dt1 <- dt["i",c(nm1,nm2),with=FALSE]
m.out[[1]] <- calcMatrix(dt1)

# group j
m <- matrix(0,cat,cat + 1)
dt1 <- dt["j",c(nm1,nm2),with=FALSE]
m.out[[2]] <- calcMatrix(dt1)

# group k
m <- matrix(0,cat,cat + 1)
dt1 <- dt["k",c(nm1,nm2),with=FALSE]
m.out[[3]] <- calcMatrix(dt1)
```

**How can I apply the function and create the list of matrix to all the groups of the data.table (especially if I try the code on a big dataset)?**

**I thought of this solution BUT IT DOES NOT WORK. The function itself does not create a matrix for each .SD and the list is not appended correctly:**

```
m.out <- list()
m.out <- dt[,calcMatrix(.SD),by = id, .SDcols = c(nm1,nm2)]
```

The function *calcMatrix* is defined as such:

```
calcMatrix <- function(x) {

  # number of "b" categories
  cat <- length(nm1)
  # vector of column indices
  col.index <- grep("^b",colnames(x))
  # number of rows in the data.table x
  row.num <- nrow(x)

  # fill in matrix
  m <- matrix(0,cat,cat + 1)
  for(i in col.index) {
    for(j in 1:(row.num - 1)) {
      m[i,] = m[i,] + as.integer(x[j,i,with=FALSE]) * c(0,as.matrix(x[j, .SD, .SDcols = nm2]))
    }
   m[i,1] = m[i,1] + as.integer(x[row.num,i,with=FALSE])
  }
  return(m)
}
```

**This function may not be optimized for R due to the two loops. IS THERE A WAY TO GET RID OF THE LOOPS?**

Edit: I can explain what I do in `calcMatrix`.

1. For each group *id*, I want to obtain a matrix with the number of
   *bi* variables as rows and the number of *bi* variables +1 as columns. I will count the number of transitions per group *id*.
2. Then I take each *bi* and check which *bj* is reach at the next *time* (basically a transition from *bi* to *bj*).
3. I then do +1 in the matrix at the cell m[i,j+1] (the first column is used for the last row).
4. When we are at the last row (last *time*), there is no transition so if
   *bi=1* at that *time*, I do +1 in the first column (transition on itself).

This way, I count all the transition from *bi* to *bj* and all the last states. That is why I compute the *lead* with the `shift` function. I can add directly the lead row to the matrix. I was wondering if this could be written differently without looping but through vectorization as it is the philosophy in R.

Comment: Please, can you provide additional information on what you want to achieve? I'm staring at your code (`shift` and `calcMatrix`) but I don't get it.

Comment: First of, thanks Uwe Block for your answer. You answered what is the most important to scale the procedure to any dataset.

Comment: Second, this my edits in the text above for more details on `calcMatrix`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two questions actually. Only one can be answered. The second on optimizing the function requires additional information.

#### How can I apply the function and create the list of matrix to all the groups of the data.table?

You may try `lapply()` to create a list of results:

```
lapply(dt[, unique(id)], function(.id) {calcMatrix(dt[id == .id, c(nm1,nm2), with=FALSE])})
```

which returns:

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    1    0
[2,]    1    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    1    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    1
[4,]    0    1    0    0    0

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    1    0    1
[2,]    1    0    1    0    1
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    1    0    1    0    1
```

Comment: Here are two variants: `lapply(split(dt, dt[,id]), function(x) calcMatrix(x[, c(nm1,nm2), with=FALSE]))` and
`lapply(split(dt[, c(nm1,nm2), with=FALSE], dt[,id]), calcMatrix)`. The package `data.table` has its own `split()`-function.